# How to open and close a Tkinter Window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I created a main menu in Tkinter and it has a button. I made a app in Tkinter also. When I click that button on the main menu it should take me to the app that I made. Its not working. Please help.
Here is my code so far.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="App in Python", command=openApp)
```

How do I import another Tkinter file onto the menu. Import filename wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to make the button open a new window using tk.Toplevel. Here is a very basic example of how to do that:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def newWindow():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    newLabel = tk.Label(top, text='new label')
    newLabel.pack()


button = tk.Button(root, text='click me', command=newWindow)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

With this, you can then put your app in the new window that gets created when you click on the button in the main window. Unfortunately, there's no easy way that I know of to just link a preexisting project to a new tkinter window, so you'll have to change your app a little bit to make it use the new window instead of the main menu window, for example.

I'll also say that I'd encourage you to avoid the from tkinter import * statement and instead to use import tkinter as tk. It makes for a bit more typing, but your code will be much clearer!